# VLOOKUP GIS Shape File Data

Tags: excel, dictionary, gis

I have a GIS shape file (shp) with numerous attributes. It's a map of a country however it only shows the state name for each region, not the suburb name. I have another excel file with the suburb name and the region ID next to each other. Is there any way to do a VLOOKUP kind of thing which a shape file to insert the suburb names.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What platform are you viewing the shapefiles in? ArcGIS, qQIS, other?

Essentially, as long as your Country shapefile DBF and suburb excel spreadsheet table share an attribute, meaning they both have a similar field with matching values, then there is definitely a way to achieve what you're wanting.  The approach all depends on the platform, however.

Comment: I'm using QGIS..... however, you are correct that there is a DBF file.... could I extract that, do a VLOOKUP in excel and then recompile the DBF. I'm assuming that the polygons are linked to the DBF via the ID field. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can edit the DBF, but it's not the best approach.

If you can join the two (refer to my previous post regarding the shapefile and table sharing an attribute) then simply right-click the layer in qGIS, go to Properties and add the Join.